# Is it possible to minimize model loading time in Forge Viewer using section planes in NWD?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I've enabled two section planes in an NWD file so that it only shows one floor level in the view. However, when I load the model in the Forge viewer, the whole building is displayed - the section planes in NWD did not carry over to the translated model in the Forge viewer. Is this not possible to do?

My hope is to minimize the model loading time by cutting the whole building to individual floor levels using the section planes in the NWD file. The Forge viewer can then load geometry for one floor only. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that Navisworks section planes are not currently supported by the Forge Model Derivative service.

To improve the loading times, I would suggest one of the following:

- use the new, heavily optimized output format SVF2: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/call-private-beta-testers-svf-performance-enhancements
- only load a subset of the objects using the `ids` option in `viewer.loadDocumentNode`: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/minimizing-viewer-workloads-loading-models-partially-selected-components-and-features-only

Comment: There are some posts on setting cut planes in Forge viewer to do the sectioning on the model - but that still require the whole model to be loaded before the cut planes could be used, right?  Meaning no reduction in model load time?

Comment: Exactly... in that case the sectioning is just a shader effect, i.e., it does not affect which parts of the model are actually loaded from the backend.

Comment: Do try the SVF2, though, we're seeing some pretty *amazing* results in terms of size reduction and runtime performance.